# Saving audio from the browser to the backend (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, audio, blob, mediarecorder

I went through a lot of answers which have already been given but did not understand.

Task : I have to get the audio from the user which should be less than one minute and then save it in the backend and send it to Google's Speech Recognition API to get the text.

I tried recording in the browser using the MediaRecorder API by using this demo over here https://mido22.github.io/MediaRecorder-sample/.

I want to get the recorded audio saved in my Django backend so we can do some post processing on it.

EDIT1: 
[Github code for media recorder api](https://github.com/Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample)

Comment: You may want to check out https://github.com/areski/django-audiofield as I believe it will likely suit your usecase.

Comment: Not sure what Question is? What issue are you having?

Comment: I want to record audio which is done in the browser and then send that audio to my backend so that I can save that audio file @guest271314

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds Yes, what issues are you having achieving requirement? Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. There does not appear to be an actual question  presented at OP?

Comment: @guest271314 I have linked the GitHub code and if you click the demo link you can see what media recorder is able to do. It records the audio and also gives the option to download. I want to record audio and save my audio in my backend.

Comment: Is the link to the `javascript` that you tried? Can you reproduce what you tried at stacksnippets? What issues are you having implementing what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 I think thats what I am asking, how can we actually send a recorded audio file from browser to our backend in Django. Any help regarding this would be great. I am not asking for the code but the method to how actually its going to work

Comment: You can post the resulting `Blob` : `let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })` at `makeLink` function to server, or pass `blob` to `FormData` instance and post `FormData` object to server using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()`

Answer (score 2):

`POST` the resulting `Blob` at `makeLink` function to server as property of a  `FormData` object

```
function makeLink() {
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type });
  let fd = new FormData;
  fd.append("audioRecording", blob);
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "/path/to/server", true);
  request.onload = function() {
    // do stuff
  }
  request.onerror = function() {
   // handle error
  }
  request.send(fd);
}
```

```
function makeLink() {
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type });
  let fd = new FormData;
  fd.append("audioRecording", blob);
  fetch("/path/to/server", {method:"POST", body:fd})
  .then(response => response.ok)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: I am developing locally and working in python with the Django framework so what exactly would be my path to server?

Comment: _"I am developing locally"_ , _"so what exactly would be my path to server?"_ The path to the `python` file at the local server you are developing at?

Comment: No, the path would be something like "http://127.0.0.1:8000/formposturl", where formposturl is defined in one of your urls.py file and points to a form view that can process the posted data. This is fairly basic stuff, read the Django docs on forms.

Answer (score -1):

I have created a simple project here:
https://github.com/Keramatfar/django_sound_file

For the backend, i use the following function:

```
def main(request):
        
    if request.method == "POST":
        audio_data = request.FILES.get('data')
        path = default_storage.save('file' + '.wav', ContentFile(audio_data.read()))
        return render(request, 'web-recorder.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'web-recorder.html')
```